# Can we say Allah is time?

Tags: allah, shirk, time

One of my friend said Allah is time and i argued it is shirk to say such a thing but he insist it is supported by sunnah. since time is a creation of Allah, it is like saying  Allah is  water another creation of his. What is the Islamic view on this ?

Comment: probably he is talking about this: http://islamqa.info/en/9571

Comment: @Enakku, Time has a beginning, Allah hasn't.

Comment: @kalahari why do you say so?! i think this is a lie. i think everybody can easily think about time coordinate and about 3 coordinates of space as infinite to both ends, as about 4d euclidean space ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space ) .

Comment: and i think, if our space is not euclidean, time is probably infinite to both ends.

Comment: @qdinar Scientists say that time is relative, can be distorted by mass or magnetic force, and also it has a beginning which is Big Bang. Theories with evidence/proof is much more solid to rely on then personal opinions.

Answer (score 1):

**ad-Dahr** is one of Allah's names that we know through Hadith Qudsi, and it's not a creation of Allah.

**ad-Dahr** is something that is infinite, i.e. it has not beginning or end.  It cannot be measured.  Sort of like an eon, but not exactly.

**ad-Dahr** is different from what we call as **the measurement of time - waqt/zaman**

So the issue is in the interpretation of ad-Dahr = Time, and mixing the definitions.

ad-Dahr isn't a creation of Allah because Allah is ad-Dahr as it comes in several hadith:

**"Allah said, "The offspring of Adam abuse ad-Dahr, and I am the Dahr; in My Hands are the night and the day."**

[Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/205) and others

Prophet said **"None of you should say, 'May ad-Dahr be disappointed. Allah is ad-Dahr."**

[Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/206)/al-Adab al-Mufrad and others

There are a few more in Musnad Ahmed where Allah clearly said **"I am ad-Dahr"**

ad-Dahr is THE Time and not time how we perceive it.

Waqt/Zaman is the creation of Allah that you're referring to, and it's relative to how we measure it.

You can probably say ad-Dahr is what controls waqt/zaman.

Some may object and mention the ayah about what the pagans said as it comes in Surah al-Jathiya 45:24:

**And they say: "There is nothing but our life of this world, we die and we live and nothing destroys us except Ad-Dahr. And they have no knowledge of it, they only conjecture.**

But as you can see, they didn't believe Allah was ad-Dahr and separated ad-Dahr from Allah, even though Allah is ad-Dahr.  They had no knowledge of it.  They blamed ad-Dahr, yet they rejected Allah.